# How to toggle a dropdown inside a paragraph element in Bootstrap3

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a lit' stuck with a simple problem I guess, but for some reasons I can't find a solution. So here I am for the first time on StackOverflow as a member asking for help.

### What is the problem, you may ask.

Well I am trying to make a **link** to **toggle a dropdown** placed in a **navbar** on *Bootstrap3*.
So this is insanely easy, yes I know. But! There's a but... There's the code I'm using and what I need to accomplish:

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
  <li class="dropdown">
    <p class="navbar-text">Signed in as <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="navbar-link">Mark Otto</a></p>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Everything is set-up from .css / .js files included and I have the whole markdown for the navbar. All I need is that this:

```html
<a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="navbar-link">Mark Otto</a>
```

to **toggle a dropdown**. In this current state it will do absolutely nothing. It will just act like a simple link and this is just annoying. It seems that the problem is that my toggle it's inside a **p** element.

I pasted the code into bootply:
[Click Here](http://bootply.com/88659)

---

### Update

I solved the problem in another manor so this question it's outdated now.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">main1<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">main2<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>          
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Main3<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">item2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm this is not what I am looking for. I don't want a dropdown menu button I want to make that link to toggle a dropdown. Anyway thank you for your answer.